# Rules for coreference resolution

Tags: anaphora

I'm trying to understand how English tracks a subject between sentences.  I believe the term is known as *Coreference Resolution*.

I'm wondering if there's a base set of rules which can define coreference and anaphora resolution.

In general you can find the subject by using [SVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb%E2%80%93object#:%7E:text=In%20linguistic%20typology%2C%20subject%E2%80%93verb,second%2C%20and%20the%20object%20third.)

The subject in most sentences comes before the verb.

> She loves him.

So in this case she is the subject,  however if we add another sentence after.

> She loves him. They are happy.

As you can see here the Subject of the next sentence *They* refers to the subject and object of the previous sentence.

Another example off the top of my head:

> She loves him. It was a cold day out.

in this example the subject *it* doesn't appear to have a relation to the previous sentence: I don't even know what I could classify the subject as?

Just from these few examples I cannot determine a set of general rules.  I don't need to cover all the scenarios but I would like to find a way to cover the majority of use cases

Comment: (1) Totally disparate sentences (disparate within the wider context, say several sentences) warrant different paragraphs. Neither 'She loves him' nor 'It was a cold day out' work as standalone, and juxtaposing them in the same sentence would properly require some finessing. // (2) The juxtaposition  'She loves him. They are happy [together].' works because there is an obvious logical referent (her and him, the couple) for 'they'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth so would you say that coreference is heavily dependent on the context and that there's little to no structure which would determine what the subject is referencing, and its more of a bunch of tiny rules that people learn over time?

Comment: Firstly, you need to alter your first sentence to 'I'm trying to understand how English tracks, between various sentences in a text, all the expressions referring to a particular referent.'  // Analysis beyond sentence level is off-topic on ELU, but I'd recommend you (1) look up articles on 'coreference resolution' and study the simpler ones, and (2) read paragraphs of simpler novels (eg childrens novels to start), photocopying paragraphs and highlighting different coreferences in different colours. Then you could (3) mix-and-paste sentences from different paragraphs and see what messes ensue.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for the response,    I was hoping there would be some research already done on this topic, but seeing as it is a very particular nuance of the language, the information probably isn't readily available.  It may take a few days but I'll break it down and post an answer on here with my findings

Comment: @johnny5 There are hundreds, if not thousands, of papers on this topic. I disagree completely with Edwin's implied advice that EL&U does not permit consideration of intra-sentential aspects of the English language. Otherwise we'd have no room for considering discourse markers or linking devices. There are hundreds of questions about such topics here.

Comment: You could try looking up any of the following terms:  - reference resolution
 - pronoun resolution
 - pronoun reference resolution
 - anaphora resolution

Comment: Yes; I should have been less sweeping: analysis of extended pasages (comprehension) is off-topic, doubly so when poetry, lyrics or avante-garde authors are breaking rules. As is essay-writing style (paragraph arrangement, etc), discourse grammar. And coreference must at least notionally involve paragraph-wide (and wider) scope.